# Getting a FB user location with RestFB

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am trying to retrieve the user's Hometown location using the RestFB. Here is the code :

`t.facebookClient=new DefaultFacebookClient("mqJHZiRx7W3Z9QdDu");
User user=t.facebookClient.fetchObject("100001108623365", User.class);
System.out.println(user.getHometownName());`

However even if the FB page lists the home location, the FB API returns null. I am submitting a valid OAuth token.

How can i get this information? If this is not possible can i retrieve the geolocation of a Post object instead?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you have the user_hometown permission for the user.

Comment: Thanks, i just read about the user_about_me permission. However, i cannot seem to be able to find how to get this permission type using the restFB.

Comment: restFB does not handle the acquisition of access tokens for you. It looks like you'll have to roll that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you are doing a server side authentication,

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/ will give you an idea about how to carry out the OAuth2.0 authentication.

The following link will give take you to the permissions page in facebook

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Make sure you give in the necessary permissions in the scope of the while performing the GET request.